# How to add a element into array from location L to R?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose I have an array A of size N and want to perform Q queries and each query is the type -
"X L R" where X is an element that I want to add in array A from location L to R.

Mathematical format like-

```
N=5
A=[1 4 3 2 4]
Q=2
X L R=[[5 1 2],
       [-5 1 3]]
```

my algorithm for this problem is like this-

```
#python code
N=int(input())
A=list(map(int,input().split()))
Q=int(input())
L=[list(map(int,input().split())) for i in range(Q)]

for i in range(Q):
   for j in range(L[i][1]-1,L[i][2]):
        A[j]=A[j]+L[i][0]
```

but my code takes a long time hence I want to reduce the time of this code.

How I can reduce the time of this code anyone has any idea please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: interview/competitive programming question? DO the same thing with C/C++ and profile the code, you will see a significant change

Comment: Can you share interview bit same problem link please..

Answer (score 2):

What you basically need is a [difference array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-array-range-update-query-o1/). That would allow you to get `Q` update queries done in `O(1)` time each, plus `O(N)` complexity to recreate the original array.

Comment: Please refer this link to understand original problem and let me know how to solve this please :- https://github.com/Akash671/programming/blob/main/CP/Algorithm/array/IMG_20220703_194951.jpg

Comment: @AkashKumar you should ask a separate StackOverflow question for that, since it is different from the current question. This post aims to answer "how to efficiently handle `Q` queries", which it successfully does.

Comment: Thank you your answer... but sir I have already solved this problems and just I need helps only on the above code which is already I have mentioned... just I want to reduce the time complexity....

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 5
a = [1, 4, 3, 2, 4]
q = 2
xlr = [[5, 1, 2], [-5, 1, 3]]

for item in xlr:
    # create the list to be inserted first
    to_add = [item[0]]*(item[2]-item[1])
    a[item[1]:item[1]] = to_add
    
print(a)
```

Inside the for loop, I first create the list that needs to be inserted at the desired location. After that, I set the list that needs to be inserted at the position identified by the element xlr[i][1].

Generated output - `[1, -5, -5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4]`

Comment: Thank you sir for answering but sir it takes also the same time...

Comment: This is as inefficient as OP’s solution. Creating a new list would also have `O(len)` complexity

Comment: Please sir refer this link to understand full problem :-  https://github.com/Akash671/programming/blob/main/CP/Algorithm/array/IMG_20220703_194951.jpg